# How to have default forgot password but custom login and registration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use the default forgot password but want to have custom login and registration

I have used generator `make:auth` and the `scaffolding` is generated

**but the problem is:**

//file web.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('login',function(){
    return view('login');
});

Route::post('login','RegistrationController@login');

Route::get('register','RegistrationController@getRegister');
Route::post('register','RegistrationController@postRegister');
```

**But All above routes takes me to default login and register page**

> but when I remove  Auth::routes(); it takes me to all custom routes

but I want login, registration as custom routes and forgot password as a default of Laravel

**my question:** I want a login and registration custom routes to be applied but for forgot password default routes of Laravel to be applied.

how can I achieve this? Please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: do you need to customize the blade's only ?

Comment: no but i want `forgot password` default route if `Auth::routes` is not present in `web/php`

Comment: well keep auth::routest(), but on top of it define new routes *** on top of auth::routes ***

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi, i have tried that but once again default `routes` is acting

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the default routes created by Auth::routes(). By default that function creates the following routes:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

You can replace Auth::routes() with the above and modify to your needs. Be aware that the controllers for these may need to be adjusted to cooperate with your customizations depending on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: but i want to use default `forgot password` built-in feature, how can i go about that?

Comment: the above contains the default routes for the password reset (middle set). just don't change that part and it will continue to use the same controller methods that Auth::routes() would. Then you can change the rest of them to your needs or remove them completely

Comment: giving some error `Route [login] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gobookyourhall1.0\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gobookyourhall1.0\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
`

Comment: did you remove the first route listed above? that is the named route 'login' and is expected as part of the default controllers. As I mentioned the controllers may need adjusting as they redirect to each other as part of the default functionality. I would start by including all the above routes and making modifications one at a time to ensure you adjust the existing ForgotPassowrdController and ResetPasswordController to meet your needs